# Concatenate Current Row and Following Row in New Column

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, concatenation

Suppose we have this data frame in R:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1,5), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 4), rep(4, 2)), brand = c("A", "B", "A", "D", "Closed", "B", "C", "D", "D", "A", "B", "Closed", "C", "Closed"))

> df
#   id  brand
#1   1      A
#2   1      B
#3   1      A
#4   1      D
#5   1 Closed
#6   2      B
#7   2      C
#8   2      D
#9   3      D
#10  3      A
#11  3      B
#12  3 Closed
#13  4      C
#14  4 Closed
```

I want to create a new variable that represents the change in the brand column from the current row to the following row, but this has to occur only within each id number.

I create the new column:

```
df$brand_chg <- ""
```

And this loop correctly accomplishes what I want to do:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

    j <- i + 1

    if(j > nrow(df)) next #to prevent error in very last row

    if (df[i,'id'] != df[j, 'id']) next #to skip loop when id changes

    df[i,'brand_chg'] <- paste(df[i,'brand'], df[j,'brand'], sep = "->") 
    #populating concatenation
}

#Results:
#   id  brand brand_chg
#1   1      A      A->B
#2   1      B      B->A
#3   1      A      A->D
#4   1      D D->Closed
#5   1 Closed          
#6   2      B      B->C
#7   2      C      C->D
#8   2      D          
#9   3      D      D->A
#10  3      A      A->B
#11  3      B B->Closed
#12  3 Closed          
#13  4      C C->Closed
#14  4 Closed
```

However, on a table with 287k rows this loop takes at least 10 minutes to run. Does anyone know of a faster way to accomplish this concatenation?

Thank you, I appreciate your insight.

Comment: untested on 287k rows `with(df, ave(brand, id, FUN = function(x) c(paste(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1), sep = '->'), '')))`

Comment: I get errors with the `with()` but when removing that the `ave()` function gives me a list of correct concatenations. Thank you! I'll have to study how exactly this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(brand_chg = ifelse(seq_along(brand) == n(), 
                              "", 
                              paste(brand, lead(brand), sep = "->")))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works and it stays in data frame form. Do you mind explaining what is happening with `seq_along(brand)==n()`?

Comment: `seq_along(brand)==n()` returns true for the last row of the group, `seq_along` is like a row index and `n()` is the number of rows per group.

Answer (score 1):

Also dplyr, just a little different, no better! Uses is.na instead of n==n()

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(is.na(lead(brand)), "", paste0(brand,"->", lead(brand))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, brand_chg := paste(brand, shift(brand, type = "lead"), sep="->"), id]
df[df[, .I[.N] , id]$V1, brand_chg := ""]
df
#    id  brand brand_chg
# 1:  1      A      A->B
# 2:  1      B      B->A
# 3:  1      A      A->D
# 4:  1      D D->Closed
# 5:  1 Closed          
# 6:  2      B      B->C
# 7:  2      C      C->D
# 8:  2      D          
# 9:  3      D      D->A
#10:  3      A      A->B
#11:  3      B B->Closed
#12:  3 Closed          
#13:  4      C C->Closed
#14:  4 Closed
```

---

Or a compact option is

```
setDT(df)[, brand_chg := c(paste(brand[-.N], brand[-1], sep="->"), ""), id]
```